# Adding multiple tags

Tags: android, android-studio, tags

I paste rows of data in the .xml file in Android Studio:

```
    ...
<item>Monday</item>
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
...
```

How do i add "item" tag pair to every row at once similar to the first one?

Comment: Can you explain more? What do you want to achieve? Dou you want adding an array or something?

Comment: I just want to figure out is there an option in Android Studio that allows to automatically add tag pair to every row of text pasted from clipboard. Live Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [https://plus.google.com/u/0/111438597118026640272/posts/hJ4HbtjGjnb](https://plus.sandbox.google.com/u/0/111438597118026640272/posts/hJ4HbtjGjnb):

I prefer the column selection mode. Assuming you pasted each item on one line, I'd turn on the column selection mode, place cursor on first item and press shift+down till the cursor is at the last item. Then type `<item>`, press end and type `</item>`

If multiple items are one line, you can place multiple cursors, but I find that tedious.﻿